# google tag manager script doesn't work after refreshing with f5 but works after crtl + f5

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have custom java script implemented as custom html in GTM. tag fires properly but the script doesn't work when I refresh only with f5. Works properly in the console each time and when I refresh with crtl + f5. It's about cashes I think but I don't know how change it to work with every refreshing. 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a parameter with random value (calculated at each refresh) to the js call or to the interested URL.